# Get path from URI throws exception

Tags: java, android, uri

I have an Android application that i'm working on and now i'm trying to get a File from an URI (i'll use an intent to get an image from gallery and then upload it to a node.js server using Ion). Te problem is it always throws an exception. I tried debugging and got the Uri.toString(). It looks something kind of like this:

```
content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A102
```

I know for a fact that it should look like this:

```
content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:102
```

I know that the %3A is a representation of :, but why does it appear in the Uri and, how can i fix it? Finally, how can i get my file from this Uri?

Comment: Its hex representation of : in uri all special character are converted to hex representation.

Answer (score 0):

> i'm trying to get a File from an URI

A `Uri` is not a file. A `Uri` does not have to point to anything on the filesystem, let alone a place that you can access.

> but why does it appear in the Uri

A `Uri` is an opaque handle. It can be whatever the `ContentProvider` wants it to be.

> how can i fix it?

You don't, any more than you "fix" `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41795342/get-path-from-uri-throws-exception` because you do not like eight-digit numbers starting with `4`. Just as the Stack Overflow Web server defines that URLs it uses, so does a `ContentProvider` define what `Uri` values it uses.

> Finally, how can i get my file from this Uri?

Ideally, you don't. You use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by that `Uri`, and Ion uses that.

If Ion does not support this and can only work with a file, use the `InputStream` to copy the bytes to some `FileOutputStream` that you control (e.g., in `getCacheDir()`). Use that file for your upload, then delete the file when you are done.